# I need like below in sql server please help out of this

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have data like below

[image]

And I need output like

wanted data

[image]

Please help me out of this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table_name
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col3 FROM table_name
ORDER BY col1 ASC
```

Comment: Thanks @sebastian Brosch

Answer (score 1):

You need `apply` :

```
select t.col1, tt.cols
from table t cross apply
     ( values (col2), (col3)
     ) tt(cols) 
order by t.col1;
```

Comment: It's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use Union ALL

```
SELECT col1   ,col2
FROM tablename
UNION ALL
SELECT col1   ,col3
FROM tablename
```